# Lost my mouse and keyboard on upgrade

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse

I'm running 18.04 LTS and just did an automatic maintenance upgrade. The kernel versions are 5.4.0-91-generic (previous) and 5.4.0-92-generic (current)

After today's upgrade, the mouse and keyboard are not recognized. If I use Grub to boot to ...91 all is well. Keyboard works fine in Grub. On ...92 I get the login screen but cannot log in without mouse or keyboard

I've tried booting to a shell with /bin/bash in the Grub line. This does nothing. I can boot to run level 3 using Grub but the keyboard is still not recognized so I can't enter commands

FWIW, I'm using a KVM switch, America Megatrends micro PC, and generic usb keyboard and wireless mouse

This same thing happened when I did a dist-upgraded to 20.04 LTS so I had to back it out

Any help would be most appreciated. I'm stuck

Comment: Can you try without the KVM switch? Or with a different keyboard? Can you access the machine over SSH?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I've removed the KVM switch and no difference. The machine is otherwise functioning properly as I can ping and ssh to the machine.

Comment: Can you ssh to it and check `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see if something was uninstalled? A bit of a long shot, but it happened to me once that `xserver-xorg-input-all` was removed when installing a package, resulting in no keyboard or mouse input to the x server.

Comment: I've checked my  apt history, starting with the upgrade that started the problems, which incidentally was the start of the log. There is an entry where I tried re-installing xserver but this was long after the problem started. Nothing has been removed. Sadly, there's not room to paste the log in the comment