# USB does not work (no mouse and keyboard) after dist-upgrade on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, usb

Did my regular dist-upgrade today, and could not use a mouse and a keyboard after reboot. USB stopped to work. Next, I did **a clean reinstall** of Ubuntu-20.04.03, and again, after I dist-upgrade'd the mouse and keyboard were gone.

I can repair USB by booting into the previous kernel 5.11.0-27.
When comparing the boot sequences in journalctl, the difference seems to start at message

```
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14:0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14:0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14:0: HC died; cleaning up
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14:0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
```

I also tried to update the firmware at my Gigabyte Z370P D3, did not help.

Appears, the same problem appeared TODAY with Ubuntu 18.04 and a different kernel:
[Lost my mouse and keyboard on upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385287/lost-my-mouse-and-keyboard-on-upgrade)
I cannot comment there, and I have no answer either.

I continue booting to the old kernel, but what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by `0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial`.
It is supported by the kernel for many years, popular in UPS monitoring interfaces. Removing it fixed the problem for me.

Could be that my device simply broke, or, more likely, this is due to some updated package - since it appeared right after `dist-upgrade`

Comment: Removed the device physically, or unload kernel driver/module?

Comment: Physically disconnected the USB cable of the UPS. I did not use it and forgot I had it plugged