# How do I uninstall a problematic kernel?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kernel, uninstall

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I got a notice that an upgrade was needed and I consented. The upgrade updated my kernel from `5.4.0-91-generic` to `...-92` and broke things. I can still boot to `...91` from GRUB.

I'm unable to spend any more time trying to resolve the upgrade problem at this time and would like to just uninstall it. However, I realize uninstalling is not the same a reverting and I am reluctant to just uninstall the `...92` upgrade as other things may be lost.

What can I do to remove the `...92` upgrade and get my machine back without damaging the OS?

The machine boots and I can SSH into it.

Comment: Would you mind telling, why did you post the duplicate of your previous post again?

Comment: My reply to @Someone: It was rather late last night and I might have inadvertently posted twice. But I see no duplicate post to remove. What have I missed?

Comment: I saw your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385287/lost-my-mouse-and-keyboard-on-upgrade) addressing the same problem with the kernel, which IMO is similar to this. But now, let's forget that... You already got 2 answers, so it doesn't matter. I took my downvote back and upvoted :D

Comment: Thank you,@Someone and thanks for the insight. I'll try to be more careful in the future

Comment: No problem :D.... Have you tried the provided answers?

Comment: I was researching the grub-customizer and only found it available for 18.04 from a private repository. i wasn't sure which approach and wanted to look at it. But, I'm not much into using private repositories. Hence, I'm now stepping through the answer from nobody.

Comment: You can install Grub customizer using `sudo apt install grub-customiser`. My answer also provides a CLI solution. It's your choice both the answers are correct :D BTW there is nothing wrong with that PPA. As its tested and trusted.

Comment: I took the non-GUI approach and am back in business. Thanks for your help and up-votes

Answer (score 4):

It is better to do that without a GUI. GRUB is too important for me to trust a program which hides what it is doing exactly behind a GUI.

1. First, create a backup of the `/etc/default/grub` file:

   ```
   cp /etc/default/grub $HOME
   ```
2. Now, open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor and add:

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
   GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
   ```
3. Update GRUB to save the changes:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot to your working kernel, so that GRUB can save your choice for the next reboot.
5. Now, list all the kernel packages:

   ```
   dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|m|h]'
   ```
6. Once identified, you can remove any kernel package with `5.4.0-92` in its name (e.g. `linux-image-5.4.0-92-generic`, `linux-headers-5.4.0-92`, `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-92-generic`, `linux-modules-5.4.0-92-generic`) via `apt remove`.
7. If you want to avoid the problematic kernel coming with a future update, then run:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
   ```

   This will put a hold on the current `linux-image-generic` package and stop it from being updated.

   You can undo it with:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark unhold linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
   ```

   but you may not want to do this, as it's possible that the following kernel update will boot without problems, and this stops the kernel from being updated to a newer version.
8. To avoid that your running kernel gets uninstalled by `apt autoremove`, you can mark the kernel and header versions you want to keep on your system as `manual`. In your case the version you want to keep using is `5.4.0-91`, so:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark manual linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I took this non-GUI approach and everything seems to be fine. My thanks to all for your help. I'm back in business

Answer (score 2):

#### Graphical User Interface

You can do that using the `grub-customizer` Package. You can install it using:

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

After installing the package you can **launch the application** using:

```
grub-customizer
```

You'll get an **interface** like:

> [image]

Right-click on the kernel **causing errors**( `5.4.0-92-generic`), and select `remove`:

> [image]

Now, right-click on the **working kernel** ( `5.4.0-91-generic`) and select `move up`:

> [image]

Click on the **save button** to save the changes:

> [image]

After doing the above run this in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo apt autoremove
```

That's it!

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/100246/1460940)

**Note**: To get support and correct drivers for the device I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 with a custom kernel. Don't mind the kernel versions in the image, they're just for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Your help is most appreciated